# Is there a machine learning method to learn the structure of a sentence instead of the words?

Tags: machine-learning

I'm trying to use HMM to do named entity recognition but later on, I found most of the sentences that contain the entities are very structured. For example:
What's Apple's price today? Than instead to teach the model to learn each word within the sentence, can i teach it to learn the structure of the sentence? Like every word after "What's " or "What is" should be the name of a kind of fruit?

Thanks!

Comment: see if you can find something usefull [in this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11892128/tutorials-for-natural-language-processing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using an HMM, consider using a conditional random field. They are very similar to HMMs, but are the discriminative version (in Ng and Jordan's terminology, HMMs and Linear Chain CRFs form a generative/discriminative pair).

The benefits of doing this are that you can define features of your word observation which are the POS tag of the current word, the POS tag of the previous word(s), etc, without making independence assumptions about these features. This would allow you to incorporate structural and lexical features into the same decision framework.

Edit: [Here's](http://repository.upenn.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1162&context=cis_papers) the original paper. [Here's](http://www.research.ed.ac.uk/portal/files/10482724/crftut_fnt.pdf) a very comprehensive tutorial.

Comment: That sounds exactly what I need. Is there a link or paper about how to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for sharing of the paper. But what I mean is the paper about combing the POS and CRF together. Cause all the CRF sequencing tagging are kind of different from the POS. It doesn't use the POS tag at all, even the stanford NER software doesn't do that. Thx

Comment: This gives you the theoretical framework to include any kind of features you like. A conditional random field operates on features of the input sequence. So you can have POS features, word features, previous tag/word features, etc. It's class of model that *allows* you to do this, rather than something that inherently does it.

Answer (score 1):

You could begin exploring that structure with something as simple as [n-grams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-gram), or try something richer like [grammar induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammar_induction).